# Odoo-8 field does not exist

Tags: inheritance, view, field, odoo, odoo-8

I want to add a Integer field under the partner_id field on the stock picking form. 
I tried inheriting this view and adding the field, but I always get the error "Field `gr_wgt` does not exist"

This is my models.py:

```
class stockpickingweight(models.Model):
_inherit = 'stock.picking'
_name = 'stockpickingweight'

gr_wgt = fields.Integer()
```

This is my views.xml:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="stock_picking_form_inherit">
        <field name="name">stock.picking.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <field name="partner_id" position="after">
                <field name="gr_wgt"/>
           </field>
        </field>
 </record>
```

I also tried with xpath but this gave me the same error. (I also tried placing it under other fields).

Comment: remove this _name = 'stockpickingweight'

Comment: user this one class StockPicking(models.Model):

Comment: Hello, the possibility of occurrence of this error is two, may be you have written view/views.xml before models/models.py or your db is not properly refreshed so suggesting uninstall your custom module and try it again.

Comment: 3 suggestions and try:

- Remove Name.
- Did you put the PY in the __init__.py?
- Try with fields.Integer('Name of field')